# Opening file saved on FTP server

Tags: java, io, ftp-client

I have a functionality for add attachment. When we attach any file, it is uploaded to FTP server. For viewing purpose, there is a link that shows the file content from FTP server within the browser itself. I can open the file after downloading it from FTP server but i don't want to download or save the file on local machine. is there any way to open the file from FTP server without downloading or saving it on local machine?

The code that i wrote.

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect(ftpServerIp);
boolean connectionStatus = ftpClient.login(ftpServerUserName, ftpServerPassword);
if(connectionStatus){
    log.info("Connected successfully.");
}

ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpServerUploadPath);
fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
boolean result = ftpClient.retrieveFile(fileName, fos);
log.info("result==>"+result);
```

Here the result is coming as `true` while retrieving the file. but i am not able to display the file contents. Is there any way to achieve it?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But retrieveFile does "download" the file and stores it under the name, according to the value of `fileName`. You should do `fos.flush(); fos.close()`.

Comment: Thanks Laune. I am doing the `fos.flush(); fos.close();` in my `finally` block. Does it download the file on local machine?

Comment: Most certainly. There's no other way to get at data on an FTP server (unless you login *there* and access the file system below the FTP root.) - Do you see the file now?

Comment: Not yet. I tried `Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);` for opening the file. Its opening the file but in the application according to the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using below code.

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.connect(ftpServerIp);
boolean connectionStatus = ftpClient.login(ftpServerUserName,    ftpServerPassword);
if(connectionStatus){
    log.info("Connected successfully.");
}
ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(ftpServerUploadPath);
InputStream stream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(fileName);
int length   = 0;
ServletContext      context  = getServletConfig().getServletContext();
String              mimetype = context.getMimeType( fileName );
response.setContentType( (mimetype != null) ? mimetype : "application/octet-stream" );
response.setHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"" );

byte[] bbuf = new byte[fileName.length()];
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(stream);

while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1))
{
    out.write(bbuf,0,length);
}
in.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
```